# jquery marquee-like animation for a div with overflow:hidden and nowrap?

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, overflow

I have a block element for song-title (an absolutely positioned h1 with max-width, nowrap and overflow:hidden) that needs to be limited to 650px wide.  if the width of the H1 is 650px, I need to start an animation that scrolls the div horizontally, back and forth, in a ping-pong-like manner.

How would I go about animating the scroll?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the most efficient or best way to solve this problem, but I ended up creating two jquery functions, to accomplish the task:

```
$.fn.pingpongscroll = function () {
    var delay = 30;
    $(this).wrapInner('<span>');
    var contentWidth = $(this).children('span').width();
    var boxWidth = $(this).width();

    if (contentWidth > boxWidth) {
        var startIndent = parseInt($(this).css('text-indent'));
        var currIndent  = startIndent;
        var left = true;
        $(this).pingpongscrollstep(contentWidth, startIndent, currIndent, left, delay);
    }
};
$.fn.pingpongscrollstep = function (contentWidth, startIndent, currIndent, left, delay) {
    if($(this).length != 0) {
        thisdelay = delay;
        if(left) {
            if(contentWidth + currIndent > $(this).width()) {
                currIndent = currIndent - 1;
                $(this).css('text-indent', currIndent);
            } else {
                left = false;
                thisdelay = thisdelay*20;
            }
        } else {
            if(currIndent < startIndent) {
                currIndent = currIndent + 1;
                $(this).css('text-indent', currIndent);
            } else {
                left = true;
                thisdelay = thisdelay*30;
            }
        }
        var thiselement = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(thiselement).pingpongscrollstep(contentWidth, startIndent, currIndent, left, delay);
        }, thisdelay);
    }
};
```

although these work well, I'm sure this is not the normal way to handle scrolling.  Also, I have no idea how to make the second function a private member of the first, so it can't be called by the site... does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

there is a jquery marquee plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/marquee/

Comment: unfortunately, this plugin only directly imitates the marquee tag, and doesn't offer ping-pong scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the [code provided by Greg Schoppe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979396/16911) to use the jQuery animation subsystem.

Timing between my version and his is a little different, but that should be easily tweakable.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.pingpongscroll = function () {
        $(this).wrapInner('<span style="white-space: nowrap">');
        var contentWidth = $(this).children('span').width();
        var boxWidth = $(this).width();

        if (contentWidth > boxWidth) {
            var startIndent = parseInt($(this).css('text-indent'));
            var currIndent  = startIndent;
            var left = true;

            var maxIndent = $(this).width() - contentWidth;
            pingpong($(this));

            function pingpong($el) {
                $el
                    .delay(2500)
                    .animate(
                        {'text-indent' : maxIndent},
                        5000,
                        'linear')
                    .delay(2500)
                    .animate(
                        {'text-indent' : startIndent},
                        5000,
                        'linear',
                        function() {
                            pingpong($el)
                        });
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```